# Apply multiple functions to a list of matrices and output answers in a data frame

Tags: r, list, function, matrix, apply

I have the following matrix:

```
mat<- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,
   2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,
   0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
   0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
   0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,
   1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,2,1,0,0,0), nrow=16, ncol=6)
dimnames(mat)<- list(c("a", "c", "f", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m", "p", "q", "s", "t", "u", "v","x", "z"), 
          c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

I have created a list of matrices using the function below:

```
lapply(seq_len(ncol(mat) - 1), function(j) do.call(cbind, 
       lapply(seq_len(ncol(mat) - j), function(i) rowSums(mat[, i:(i + j)]))))
```

In this function, columns in the original matrix are combined using a moving window method. First, the window size is 2 such that the data in two columns are combined. The window shifts 1 step (1 column) and the next set of two columns are combined. The output is a matrix for each window size. The window size continues to increase such that, the window  increases to 3 columns and the results from 3 columns are output into a new matrix. This continues until the window is the size of the maximum number of columns.

I need to run a series of functions on each matrix within the list and output the answers into a data frame. The functions I need to apply are:

1. Calculate total frequency for each row (ie. row totals ). I attempted this function:

   ```
   freq <- rowSums(mat[i:(i + j),])
   ```
2. Calculate mean frequency for each row (ie. row totals/length of row). I attempted this function:

   ```
   mean_freq <- rowSums(mat[i:(i + j),])/length(mat[i:(i + j),])
   ```
3. Multiply the window size * pi * 25.

   ```
   total_window_size <- length(ncol(mat) - j))*pi*25
   ```
4. Divide the mean frequency for each row by the total window size.

   ```
   density <- mean_freq/total_window_size
   ```

Below are the expected results for the functions above for each matrix in this example list (i.e., `result_mat1`, `result_mat2`...). The data frame `result_df` combines all the results for each sub data frame and is the final output I need:

df for window size 2

```
result_mat1 <- data.frame( window_size= rep("2",80), 
                     combined_cols= c(rep("1_2",16), rep("2_3",16), rep("3_4",16), rep("4_5",16), rep("5_6",16)),
                     row_names= c("a", "c", "f", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m", "p", "q", "s", "t", "u", "v","x", "z"),
                     freq=c(6,3,2,2,6,2,1,2,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,2),
                     mean_freq=(c(6,3,2,2,6,2,1,2,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,2)/5), 
                     total_window_size= rep(157.08, 16))
result_mat1$density<- result_mat1$mean_freq/result_mat1$total_window_size
```

df for window size 3

```
result_mat2 <- data.frame( window_size= rep("3",64), 
                     combined_cols= c(rep("1_2_3",16), rep("2_3_4",16), rep("3_4_5",16), rep("4_5_6",16)),
                     row_names= c("a", "c", "f", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m", "p", "q", "s", "t", "u", "v","x", "z"),
                     freq=c(6,4,3,3,7,3,1,2,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,2),
                     mean_freq=(c(6,4,3,3,7,3,1,2,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,2)/5), 
                     total_window_size= rep(235.62, 16))
result_mat2$density <- result_mat2$mean_freq/result_mat2$total_window_size
```

df for window size 4

```
result_mat3 <- data.frame( window_size= rep("4",48), 
                                 combined_cols= c(rep("1_2_3_4",16), rep("2_3_4_5",16), rep("3_4_5_6",16)),
                                 row_names= c("a", "c", "f", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m", "p", "q", "s", "t", "u", "v","x", "z"),
                                 freq=c(6,3,3,3,7,3,1,2,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,2),
                                 mean_freq=(c(6,3,3,3,7,3,1,2,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,2)/5), 
                                 total_window_size= rep(314, 16))
result_mat3$density <- result_mat3$mean_freq/result_mat3$total_window_size
```

df for window size 5

```
result_mat4 <- data.frame( window_size= rep("5",32), 
                      combined_cols= c(rep("1_2_3_4_5",16), rep("2_3_4_5_6",16)),
                      row_names= c("a", "c", "f", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m", "p", "q", "s", "t", "u", "v","x", "z"),
                      freq=c(6,3,2,2,6,2,1,2,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,2),
                      mean_freq=(c(6,3,2,2,6,2,1,2,1,2,3,2,1,2,4,2)/5), 
                      total_window_size= rep(392.5, 16))
result_mat4$density <- result_mat4$mean_freq/result_mat4$total_window_size
```

df for window size 6

```
result_mat5 <- data.frame( window_size= rep("6",16), 
                      combined_cols= c(rep("1_2_3_4_5_6",16)),
                      row_names= c("a", "c", "f", "h", "i", "j", "l", "m", "p", "q", "s", "t", "u", "v","x", "z"),
                      freq=c(4,2,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,3,1),
                      mean_freq=(c(4,2,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,3,1)/5), 
                      total_window_size= rep(471, 16))
result_mat5$density <- result_mat5$mean_freq/result_mat5$total_window_size
```

Final data frame with results for all sub data frames combined

```
result_df <- rbind(result_mat1, result_mat2, result_mat3, result_mat4, result_mat5)
```

I need help applying those 4 functions to each element of the list and output the results to one data frame.

Comment: I am a bit confused.  You have this function `lapply(seq_len(ncol(mat) - 1), function(j) do.call(cbind, 
       lapply(seq_len(ncol(mat) - j), function(i) rowSums(mat[, i:(i + j)]))))` and then you showed it by splitting it

Comment: I do not want to split the list. I want to apply the set of functions over each element of the list to produce `result_df`. The individual dfs I show for each element (ie. `result_mat1` and `result_mat2`) are my  intermediary attempts to produce the final output I need `result_df`.

Comment: @Danielle I would be happy to help, but the question is a bit of confusing. Consider breaking into smaller pieces with smaller data sets. Why is it even important to know how the list of matrices was obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start.  I'm not sure how the `combined_cols` is supposed to be added to each data.frame since it is a different size (seems each is longer than all of the other data.frame columns.)  I'm not sure if all of these calculations are exactly right, but this at least demonstrates the crux of the question 'how to iterate through a list, assemble some data.frames with results, and merge them into one big data.frame.)

```
myList <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(mat) - 1), function(j) do.call(cbind, lapply(seq_len(ncol(mat) - j), function(i) rowSums(mat[, i:(i + j)]))))
myListOutput <- list()

for (i in 1:length(myList)) {
  print(i)
  myMat = myList[[i]]

  freq <- rowSums(myMat)
  window_size = rep(as.character(i + 1), length(freq))
  # your final data sample shows dividing by 5 on each one, 
  # but your pseudo code shows something to do with the columns
  mean_freq <- rowSums(myMat)/(ncol(myMat))  
  total_window_size <- rep((i+1)*pi*25, length(freq))
  density <- mean_freq/total_window_size

  myDf = data.frame(window_size, freq, mean_freq, total_window_size, density)

  myListOutput[[i]] <- myDf 

}

result_df = do.call(rbind, myListOutput)
```

Comment: Thank you. This  successfully shows me how to apply functions to a list of matrices. It omits the the `combined_cols` column, which is fine for this purpose. However, there is one function that is calculated incorrectly given my question so it may be worth a correction to your current post for sake of consistency with the OP. `total_window_size` should be the product of `window_size` (number of columns combined) * pi*25. If I am reading it correctly, currently you multiply the total number of columns in the newly constructed matrix *pi*25.

Comment: I think I adjusted it?

Comment: I tried that, but if you run that loop through the original data, then there is an error `Error in window_size * pi : non-numeric argument to binary operator`. I think you need to index which window size

Comment: How about (i+1) per the above.  If this was helpful to you, please consider marking the answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thank you for this help. I have accepted the answer.